# How to not emit local symbols in NASM so that GDB disas won't stop at them?

Tags: linux, assembly, linker, nasm, elf

I'm trying to write some assembly programs using nasm on linux.  Everything is good, but I make heavy use of local symbols (.loop, .else, etc.), which is a pain when debugging, because these symbols are emitted to the symbol table, e.g.:

```
[BITS 32]
global main
section .text
main:
    do stuff
.else:
    do other stuff
```

will produce a disassembly that looks like:

```
<main>:
00000000      do stuff
<main.else>:
00000000      do other stuff
```

which is a bit annoying just because gdb will think these are all separate functions, so when I 'disas' it will only disassemble a couple of instructions before it runs into another label and stops.

Is there a way to suppress emitting these symbols to the ELF symbol table using nasm under linux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't found a way to do it directly with `nasm`, however if you link your object with `ld`, then you have at your disposal a very handy switch.
Quoting from ld's [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html):

> -x    --discard-all
>          Delete all local symbols.
>
> -X    --discard-locals
>          Delete all temporary local symbols.  (These symbols start with
>          system-specific local label prefixes, typically .L for ELF
>          systems or L for traditional a.out systems.)

so if you have, for example, this:

```assembly
section .data
    hello:     db 'Hello world!',10
    helen:     equ $-hello           
    hi:        db 'Hi!',10
    hilen:     equ $-hi
section .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov eax,4            
    mov ebx,1            
    mov ecx,hello        
    mov edx,helen                        
    int 80h
.there:
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1   
    mov ecx,hi
    mov edx,hilen
    int 80h
.end:
    mov eax,1
    mov ebx,0
    int 80h
```

and then build, link (and run) it like this:

```
$ nasm -g -f elf32 prog.asm && ld -x prog.o -o prog && ./prog
Hello world!
Hi!
```

then, when you load it in `gdb`, you get this:

```
$ gdb prog
.....
Reading symbols from prog...done.
(gdb) disas _start
Dump of assembler code for function _start:
   0x08048080 <+0>: mov    $0x4,%eax
   0x08048085 <+5>: mov    $0x1,%ebx
   0x0804808a <+10>:    mov    $0x80490b8,%ecx
   0x0804808f <+15>:    mov    $0xd,%edx
   0x08048094 <+20>:    int    $0x80
   0x08048096 <+22>:    mov    $0x4,%eax
   0x0804809b <+27>:    mov    $0x1,%ebx
   0x080480a0 <+32>:    mov    $0x80490c5,%ecx
   0x080480a5 <+37>:    mov    $0x4,%edx
   0x080480aa <+42>:    int    $0x80
   0x080480ac <+44>:    mov    $0x1,%eax
   0x080480b1 <+49>:    mov    $0x0,%ebx
   0x080480b6 <+54>:    int    $0x80
End of assembler dump.
(gdb)
```

where the disassembly is not hindered by the local symbols any more.

Comment: Couldn't find any options to control symbol properties either. Looks like NASM is less flexible than GAS.

Comment: I was almost certain that there would be some hidden option for this in nasm, but my search was fruitless. Anyway, ld seems to do the job.

Comment: @robert-mason Thanks. Glad I was able to help.

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心法轮功六四事件 - how do you do it with GAS?

Comment: Found it: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html#Symbol-Names

Comment: @maxschlepzig yes, `.Lsymbol` and `1:` don't show on object at all, so GDB ignores them. The downside is that you can't break at them either: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55226798/how-to-make-local-labels-in-gnu-gas-elf-output-that-gdb-can-break-on-but-not-cout