# gdb - how to disassemble whole function including loops

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb, nasm, debug-symbols

**Explanation:**
I am using GDB to disassembly my self-written ELF64 executables which are assembled using NASM.
When I try to disassemble using `disassemble main`, I only get the following output:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x0000000000401110 <+0>:     mov    rbp,rsp
0x0000000000401113 <+3>:     mov    ebx,0x400
End of assembler dump.
```

GDB obviously only gives me the first two lines, the ones before the loop whose start is indicated with `.loop_clear` begins.
When I try to specify lines like `disassemble 0x0000000000401116, 0x0000000000401119`, I get the following output:

```
0x0000000000401116 <main+6>: add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
0x0000000000401118 <main.loop_clear+0>:      cmp    rbx,0x0
```

As can be seen, there are lines that aren't shown in the first dump.
In the next try, I try to explicitely disassemble `main.loop_clear` by calling `disassemble main.loop_clear` but am left with `Attempt to extract a component of a value that is not a structure.`

Obviously the commands I am using or the syntax is wrong, but I couldn't find useful information during my research in order to fix this issue.

**Question:**
Hence my question: How is it possible to create a complete and coherent dump of the disassembled executable if the function that is being disassembled contains labels/loops?
Furthermore, is it possible to disassemble the loop for itself?

**Source:**

```
global main

section .text
main:

    ;initialize base pointer (rbp)
    mov     rbp, rsp

    ;set stack frame size and clear
    mov     rbx, 0x400
    .loop_clear:
    cmp     rbx, 0x0
    je      .exit_clear
    mov     byte [rsp], 0x0
    dec     rsp
    dec     rbx
    jmp     .loop_clear
    .exit_clear:

    ;prepare array index pointer
    mov     rcx, rsp

    ;transpiled brainfuck source
    mov bl, [rcx]
    add bl, 65
    mov [rcx], bl
    mov rsi, rcx
    mov rdx, 0x1
    mov rdi, 0x1
    mov rax, 0x1
    syscall               ; write(fd=1, buf, size=1 byte)

    ;exit gracefully
    mov     rax, 0x3
    mov     rdi, 0x0
    syscall               ; close(0)
    ret
```

Comment: If you specified `global main.loop_clear` for each of the local labels perhaps that would work around part of the issue. Just guessing though.

Comment: Oh gdb might not understand that a dot can be part of a label though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944547/break-at-local-label-using-gdb-for-nasm-assembly#comment65248615_38944547 Quoting the label with a dot may help.

Comment: Another related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33624619/how-to-not-emit-local-symbols-in-nasm-so-that-gdb-disas-wont-stop-at-them

Comment: Thank you very much, this is working!
I have to admit, that I probably could have come up with the same solution if I would have spent more time searching ;)
Sorry for not putting in enough effort

Answer (score 3):

NASM constructs label names by concatenating local labels onto the last non-local label.  These show up in the symbol table as regular labels, which of course GDB expects to only find on whole functions.

You *can* do `disas 'main.loop_clear'` - quoting the label name prevents the `.` from being treated as the C struct-member operator.

**I usually use GDB's `layout reg` to show the disassembly *window* which avoids this problem for the label names NASM constructs**.  When stopped at the current position, disassembly continues past labels.  And you can scroll forward/backward in disassembly using the arrow keys.  Plus you get colour highlighting of the register(s) that changed when you stepped.  See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for more GDB tips, and also [the GDB manual for Text UI mode](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI.html)

My `~/.gdbinit` contains:

```
set disassembly-flavor intel
layout reg

set print static-members off
set print pretty on
```

Running `gdb ./a.out` and then `starti` to stop before any user-space instruction, or in this case `start` (to stop at the top of main) gives me output like this:

```
...

│r14            0x0                 0                                       r15            0x0                 0                                       │
│rip            0x401110            0x401110 <main>                         eflags         0x246               [ PF ZF IF ]                            │
│cs             0x33                51                                      ss             0x2b                43                                      │
│ds             0x0                 0                                       es             0x0                 0                                       │
│fs             0x0                 0                                       gs             0x0                 0                                       │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
│B+>0x401110 <main>                 mov    rbp,rsp                                                                                                     │
│   0x401113 <main+3>               mov    rbx,0x400                                                                                                   │
│   0x40111a <main.loop_clear>      cmp    rbx,0x0                                                                                                     │
│   0x40111e <main.loop_clear+4>    je     0x40112c <main.exit_clear>                                                                                  │
│   0x401120 <main.loop_clear+6>    mov    BYTE PTR [rsp],0x0                                                                                          │
│   0x401124 <main.loop_clear+10>   dec    rsp                                                                                                         │
│   0x401127 <main.loop_clear+13>   dec    rbx                                                                                                         │
│   0x40112a <main.loop_clear+16>   jmp    0x40111a <main.loop_clear>                                                                                  │
│   0x40112c <main.exit_clear>      mov    rcx,rsp                                                                                                     │
│   0x40112f <main.exit_clear+3>    mov    bl,BYTE PTR [rcx]                                                                                           │
│   0x401131 <main.exit_clear+5>    add    bl,0x41                                                                                                     │
│   0x401134 <main.exit_clear+8>    mov    BYTE PTR [rcx],bl                                                                                           │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
native process 46953 In: main                                                                                                        L7    PC: 0x401110 
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
Reading symbols from ./a.out...
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x401110: file bf.asm, line 7.
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at bf.asm:7
(gdb)
```

Note that `layout reg` has gotten really flaky in recent GDB for executables built from asm source.  e.g. `tui disab` at this point would crash GDB.  And it's not rare for GDB to crash when the program exits.  I guess I should report some bugs if this isn't common knowledge.

But it's usable enough still.

Answer (score 2):

You could fix this by removing the local labels (with some loss of debuggability):

```
$ nasm -f elf64 foo.asm && nm foo.o
0000000000000000 T main
000000000000001a t main.exit_clear
0000000000000008 t main.loop_clear

$ strip --strip-unneeded foo.o && nm foo.o
0000000000000000 T main
```

```
gdb -q --batch -ex 'disas main' foo.o

Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000000000 <+0>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000000003 <+3>:     mov    $0x400,%ebx
   0x0000000000000008 <+8>:     cmp    $0x0,%rbx
   0x000000000000000c <+12>:    je     0x1a <main+26>
   0x000000000000000e <+14>:    movb   $0x0,(%rsp)
   0x0000000000000012 <+18>:    dec    %rsp
   0x0000000000000015 <+21>:    dec    %rbx
   0x0000000000000018 <+24>:    jmp    0x8 <main+8>
   0x000000000000001a <+26>:    mov    %rsp,%rcx
   0x000000000000001d <+29>:    mov    (%rcx),%bl
   0x000000000000001f <+31>:    add    $0x41,%bl
   0x0000000000000022 <+34>:    mov    %bl,(%rcx)
   0x0000000000000024 <+36>:    mov    %rcx,%rsi
   0x0000000000000027 <+39>:    mov    $0x1,%edx
   0x000000000000002c <+44>:    mov    $0x1,%edi
   0x0000000000000031 <+49>:    mov    $0x1,%eax
   0x0000000000000036 <+54>:    syscall 
   0x0000000000000038 <+56>:    mov    $0x3,%eax
   0x000000000000003d <+61>:    mov    $0x0,%edi
   0x0000000000000042 <+66>:    syscall 
   0x0000000000000044 <+68>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

Or you could single-quote the `main.loop_clear` in GDB `disas` command.